# Cannot declare a UserControl in file code

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have had a problem. I create an UserControl and I save it, it appears in ToolBox. I can drop it from ToolBox normally. However, I can not declare it as a variable in the file code. Can you help me, please? And it is file code of UserControl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Music_Player_Project_IT008N13.Controls;

namespace Music_Player_Project_IT008N13.Music_design_User_Control
{
    public partial class LocationPanel : UserControl
    {
        public LocationPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public delegate void DoEvent(string maSo, string tenSV, string khoa, string diemTB);
        public event DoEvent RefeshDgv;
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's file code in file LocationPanel.cs. If you need more, I will up code more

Comment: Can you show us how you are trying to declare it as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

When you "drop it from the ToolBox normally", the Designer generates a member declaration for a new user control and *also* adds it to the forms `Control` collection. As I understand it, your question states that you would like to declare your user control variable **in code**. If this is the goal, we have to do the same thing that the Designer would do and add it to the `Controls` collection of the container you want to put it in.

---

**Example**

*Add a FlowLayoutPanel using code, then add 3 CustomUserControls to it also in code.*

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Declare a flow layout panel in code.
        // Add it to the main form control collection
        var flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            Name = "flowLayoutPanel",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };
        this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel);

        for (char c = 'A'; c < 'D'; c++)
        {
            var userControl = new CustomUserControl
            {
                Name = $"userControl{c}",  // No space, start with lowercase
                Text = $"UserControl {c}", // Visible name
                Margin = new Padding(10, 2, 10, 2),
                Width = flowLayoutPanel.Width - 20,
            };
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(userControl);
        }

        // T E S T
        CustomUserControl? loopback = GetUserControl("userControlA");
        Debug.Assert(loopback != null, "Expecting to retrieve user control by name");
    }
```

Then, to use the control, retrieve it from the Controls collection by name.

```
    CustomUserControl? GetUserControl(string name)
    {
        var layoutPanel = Controls["flowLayoutPanel"] as FlowLayoutPanel;
        return layoutPanel.Controls[name] as CustomUserControl;
    }
}
```

Where:

```
public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomUserControl() => InitializeComponent();
    public new string Text
    {
        get => label1.Text; 
        set => label1.Text = value;
    }
}
```